# Converting a list of strings to a list of integers in Python

Tags: python, list

I have the following code which is used to extract a substring from each line of text on a file and put in a list of strings.

```
distribution = []

with open("./Output_Files/datafile.txt", "r") as fileRead:
         for line in fileRead:
             distr_chop = line.split()[3:]
             distribution.append(distr_chop)
```

Then I convert each string in the list to an integer:

```
distribution = [int(i) for i in distribution]
```

However, I get an error when printing the list.

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
> number, not 'list'

1. What is wrong with my code?
2. What other way could I extract the substring directly to an integer?

Comment: Please do not SHOUT!  It is considered rude.

Comment: `distr_chop` is a list

Comment: Using `[3:]` is a slice. It makes a list.

Comment: Try `distribution.extend(distr_chop)`

Comment: Each line is turned into a list. Do you want to keep  that structure. Should each item in distribution be a list of the integers from that line?

Comment: thanks Chris that works

Answer (score 1):

`distr_chop` is a list.

If it is a single element list, you can do

```
...
distribution.append(distr_chop[0])

# then proceed to use the list comprehension to convert each element to an integer
```

Answer (score 1):

dist_chop is in this case a list of 4th through nth "words" of the line thus distribution is an array of arrays which is not what I imagine you wanted.

use `distribution += distr_chop` if you actually wanted all the things after the 3rd or `distribution.append(line.split())[3]` if you just wanted just one element from each line